# Couchbase 4.0 Python SDK authentication error on passwordless bucket

Tags: python, sdk, couchbase

I am experiencing issue when I am trying to retrieve documents based on the view.

```
result = bucket.query("view","view", limit=1, streaming=True)
for row in result:
    bucket.replace("aass_brewery-juleol", row.docid)
```

The exception:

```
couchbase.exceptions._AuthError_0x2 (generated, catch AuthError): <Key=u'aass_brewery-juleol', RC=0x2[Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src/multiresult.c,309)>
```

The bucket doesn't have any authentication beside `Standard port (TCP port 11211. Needs SASL auth.)`

Comment: That is certainly strange, especially considering the view executes OK. Does this always happen, how do you connect to the bucket, and which version of the Python (and C) SDK are you using?

Comment: Python: 2.7.6, the SDK: python 2.0, `ldd --version`: ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.9) 2.19. What is really strange, is that I was able to do a dirty trick by calling `c = Couchbase.connect(bucket='bucket', host='x.x.x.x')`, which helped to execute the code, but `connection` is deprecated. So maybe there is a problem in the `pip` package. The version I am using is: 2.1.0.

Comment: Indeed. This sounds a bit strange. You can get the C version by doing `Bucket.lcb_version()`

Comment: Version: `('2.6.1', 132609) `

Comment: You can try to enable logging to see more detailed information: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/python/collecting-information-and-logging.html